# Executing a post-test action in Test Studio

Tags: katalon-studio, telerik-test-studio

With testing technologies like JUnit, TestNG, and Katalon Studio, there exist setup and teardown methods. In TestNG, there is even a `beforeTestSuite()`,`afterTestSuite()`. I am looking for an equivalent in Test Studio, namely for either logging out or clearing the cache, for every test ran in a test list.